# django relationship how to map an indirect relation in model

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have three models

```
class Venue(models.Model):
  property_values = models.ManyToManyField('feature.PropertyValue')

class Feature(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)

class PropertyValue(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
  feature = models.ForeignKey('Feature', null=False, blank=False)
```

In this I want to be able to configure 'feature' in venue model saying that belongs to it via property value.

Like

```
class Venue(models.Model):
  property_values = models.ManyToManyField('feature.PropertyValue')
  feature = models.ManyToManyField(via property_value something)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have access to feature through property_values

```
one = Venue.objects.first()
one.property_vaues.all()[0].feature
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add` methods of Django objects:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

```
venue = Venue.objects.get(id=1) # example
feature = Feature.objects.get(id=1) # example
venue.property_values.add(feature)
```

You can remove using `remove` function also